# does single user mode bypass PAM and always allow console login?

Tags: pam

I am investigating setting up a RHEL 7 linux system to authenticate with active directory along with MFA.  In doing do I am being given instructions that modify various `pam.d` files such as `system-auth`.

My question(s):

- Does booting into single user mode bypass or preempt what is defined in PAM?
- Can I **always** rely on booting my server in single user mode and logging in as root as a reliable fallback {nuclear} option in order to undo incorrect pam.d configurations as I figure things out?

*I am worried about messing up pam settings and preventing all login to linux such that I would have to reinstall linux from dvd to recover from a screw up.*

Comment: pam module are not correlated to boot process, what you inted should be OK (and the way to do it by the way). If you can have a virtual guest with snapshot capacity that would be even better.

Comment: What init system are you using?

Comment: it is rhel 7.9 x86-64... systemd i believe